# How to translate sudoku XV boards in CNF format?

Tags: ai-design, logic, sudoku, conjunctive-normal-form

I'm trying to implement the logic for a Sudoku XV puzzle, that it's essentially a standard sudoku with the addition of X and V markers between some pairs of squares. X markers in adjacent pairs requires that the sum of the two values is 10. Similarly, the V marks requires that the sum of the values is equal to 5.

(Assume that $$ S_{xyz} $$ stands for [digit][row][column])

I've written the following CNF formulae that handle the logic of a standard Sudoku puzzle:

There is at least one number in each entry:
$$ \bigwedge_{x=1}9\bigwedge_{y=1}9\bigwedge_{z=1}9S_{xyz} $$

Each number appears at most once in each row:
$$ \bigwedge_{y=1}9\bigwedge_{z=1}9\bigwedge_{x=1}{8\bigwedge_{i=x+1}9}{(\lnot S}_{xyz\ }\vee\lnot S_{iyz\ }) $$

Each number appears at most once in each column:
$$ \bigwedge_{x=1}9\bigwedge_{z=1}9\bigwedge_{y=1}{8\bigwedge_{i=x+1}9}{(\lnot S}_{xyz\ }\vee\lnot S_{xiz\ }) $$

Each number appears at most once in each 3x3 sub-grid:
$$
\bigwedge_{z=1}9\bigwedge_{i=0}2\bigwedge_{j=0}{2\bigwedge_{x=1}2\bigwedge_{y+1}3\bigwedge_{k=x+1}3\bigwedge_{l=1,\ \ y \neq l}3}{(\lnot S}_{(3i+x)(3j+y)z\ }\vee\lnot S_{(3i+k)(3j+l)z\ })
$$

Unfortunately, I'm stuck, and I don't really know how I can express the logic for X and V markers, and most importantly how to invalidate squares that contain neither an X nor a V marker that have digits summing to 5 or 10.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a new contributor so I can only add a comment in an answer post. This is a very general comment. The solving logic of a sudoku puzzle resides least in the visible digits (entries) than in the invisible candidates. The candidates state space can be represented by a 9x9x9x9 boolean matrix, the coordinates of which are (candidate, row, column, block). In that space the X and V logics can easily be expressed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey AI moderator! Couldn't you instead comment on your own work? The Answer text editor doesn't even accept the CR character, which is the basics since the invention of the typewriter, hence the name. Obviously the AI who designed it, is much more "A" than "I", and by definition it has no experience of reality !